# Is creating a company library in electronic format a good way to improve the working environment?

Tags: company-culture

[It seems community prefers e-books over physical](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47842/is-creating-a-company-library-a-good-way-to-improve-the-working-environment) books when dealing with arranging a library in the workplace.

I think one of the main improvements that having a company library can bring is giving the workers the chance to share the knowledge they've got from reading the books from the library (e.g. passing one of them to other person or having a top-10 list with the most requested books in the library).

I'm afraid going the e-book way will make the effort more of an individual one, instead of a shared experience, since buying an electronic copy and sharing it could be difficult (or even could raise legal/moral issues).

So my question is:

- How can you create an electronic company library to let your coworkers gain knowledge and then share it to the rest of the company?
- Are there any evidence on how well does it work?

Comment: I prefer a physical library always, but the answer in your linked question is right - you need a not insignificant amount of resources to create and maintain such a library.

Comment: Use a company knowledge base to share knowledge and experience.  It's searchable and editable.  Beyond that, use Google :)

Comment: "Are there any evidence on how well does it work?" We are not a research service. Do your own research. Voting to close.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan That's not how I read that question. More like "does anyone happen to know of any research...." not "please research this and report back"

Comment: "How can you" is offtopic here, being a question of software and licensing. Evidence: Many technical publishers offer online access to their publications for a fee; try asking them for "reference accounts" you can talk to for their expediences. How well it works will also depend heavily on your users and their needs.

Answer (score 2):

> How can you create an electronic company library to let your coworkers
>   gain knowledge and then share it to the rest of the company?

The simplest way is to get an enterprise license subscription to an online service for electronic books.

Some services will set up recommendations, and some will allow you to use your own local recommendations.

Comment: My company uses such a service, and I can see all of the lists created by other folks in the same organization that they have shared. Typically, the lists are around subject matter, but there is one of books authored by our coworker, so there is a lot of flexibility. What it lacks though is some overall moderation and organization, so if you wanted to create a "recommended reading list" it would require some involvement of management.